# Images Inserted in WordPress page/post not showing, but showing image name instead

Tags: wordpress, media, posts

I am running a Wordpress 3.6.1 installation.

When I try to insert an image into a post, it shows the image name instead of the image.

I checked out the uploaded image permalink and it is showing me something like this

```
telegraphng.com/?attachment_id=22825
```

Instead of something like this:

```
http://telegraphng.com/2013/10/claims-incompetence-sponsored-opposition-s/dosu-fatokun/
```

Kindly help me figure out what the problem is.

regards

Answer (score 0):

When you insert the image into your post you will need to specify where it links to. You have the following options:

- Media File
- Attachment Page
- Custom URL
- None

Depending on which one you select you will get a different result.

I believe you need to select "media file" if you want the image to show.